# Correct syntax of assignment operator (member function) implementation for a template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

Here is the .hpp file:

```
template<typename T>
LinkedQueue<T> operator=(const LinkedQueue<T> & lhs, const LinkedQueue<T> & rhs)
{
  m_data = rhs.m_data;
  m_next = rhs.m_next;
}
```

The error says that first line must be a nonstatic member function.  Here is the class it is in:

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedQueue:public AbstractQueue<T>
{
public:
  T m_data;
  LinkedQueue *m_next;

  LinkedQueue<T> operator=(const LinkedQueue<T> & rhs);
  LinkedQueue();
  void clear();
  void enqueue(T x);
  void dequeue();
  const T& front() const;
  bool isEmpty() const;

};
```

Any idea as to what silly thing I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you change the question title? It's not a good title.

Comment: A more descriptive question title might attract more answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a class qualifier to the function definition, and remove the unused `lhs` parameter:

```
template<typename T>
LinkedQueue<T>& LinkedQueue::operator=(const LinkedQueue<T> & rhs)
//            ^--- & should be added to the declaration, too
{
    m_data = rhs.m_data;
    m_next = rhs.m_next;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should write look like this;

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedQueue:public AbstractQueue<T>
{
public:
  T m_data;
  LinkedQueue *m_next;

  LinkedQueue<T> & operator=(const LinkedQueue<T> & rhs)
  {
      if (this != &rhs)
      {
          m_data = rhs.m_data;
          m_next = rhs.m_next;
      }

      return *this;
  }
  LinkedQueue();
  void clear();
  void enqueue(T x);
  void dequeue();
  const T& front() const;
  bool isEmpty() const;

};
```